# re-saving uploaded file effecting file format - flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I am getting one picture in the POST request, when saving it for the first time, it works perfectly. But when I re-save it to another directory, it saves the image but format of file is damaged in a way that it doesn't open. I have tried different patterns of getting image and saving it within an endpoint but always, the image saved at the second step is corrupted.

```py
 uploadedImage = request.files["Image"]
 try:
        uploadedImage = request.files["Image"]
        filename= UserID+"_"+Type+".jpg"
        uploadedImage.save(os.path.join("./uploads" , filename)) //WORKS

        uploadedImage2 = request.files["Image"]
        uploadedImage2.save("./allData/"+filename) //CORRUPTS THE FILE FORMAT
 except:
        ......
```

I have tried swapping saving, same happens, the later causes the problem. [image: Here is what how the picture saves.]

Also searched over the internet to find relevant issue but couldn't find any. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `os.path.join` for first image.
Why are you not using it for the second one??
Try using it as it's a windows machine path separator is `\\`

Also instead of saving it again try to copy from first location to second location. It's best I suppose.

Comment: I have tried using ```os.path.join``` as well, same result. I can copy from one location to another, but that's not best in my case because there might be some cases where I need to store in any one of the locations.